# New post after adding CNAME file to github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a personal jekyll based website hosted on Github pages. And I used to access it using username.github.io. But recently I added a domain name to my Github pages. Everything works perfectly.

But after writing and committing a post on master branch, the post doesn't show up on Github pages. It compiles perfectly on my local system. It's been more than 1 hour since I pushed my post to Github master branch.

Can anyone tell me if anything is wrong.

Comment: Probably there were some issues on Github's end. Everything is working fine now and my blog post is visible.

Comment: You should check if you have defined a timezone for your blog. Github's servers may have another setup and you will have delays for all your posts in the future.

Comment: Could also be locally cached on your system